# Analytic function in the open unit disc

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sin(z^{n})$ defines an analytic function in the open unit disc $D=\{z: |z|<1\}$.

I showed that $|\sin(z)| \le C |z|$ where $C$ is a constant: $1 \lt C \lt \infty$.

I am wondering then if my proof is valid by concluding that 
the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sin(z^{n})$ has to be at least greater or equal to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty|z^{n}|$ which is 1. Therefore the series is analytic in D.

The question is then what happens on the boundary. I tried to show that $|\sin(z^n)| \gt 1$ for $|z|=1$ thus the term does not converge to 0 as n goes to $\infty$ but I always find as lower bound 0 which does not help.

Comment: Your series is not a power series so it doesn't have a radius of convergence. Show that your series converges uniformly on $0 \leq |z| \leq r$ where $r < 1$ using the Weierstrass $M$-test and the estimate you wrote (justify it appropriately!) and use the theorem that a uniform limit of analytic functions is analytic.

Comment: yes I was confused by the term in the sum, now it makes sense. Thx!

Comment: @levap It is not a power series but it does have a radius of convergence

Comment: @reuns: The notion of "radius of convergence" is defined only for power series. A general function series (which is not of the form of a power series) has a domain of convergence, domain of uniform convergence, etc but it doesn't have a notion of a radius of convergence (because usually there is no disc in which the series converges and diverges outside the disc). Even if the domain of convergence of a function series is by coincidence a disc, one shouldn't use the term "radius of convergence" to describe this disc.

Comment: @levap : Radius of convergence means a series (or sequence) of (complex analytic) functions which converges for $|z| < R$ and diverges for $|z| > R$. Power series always have a radius of convergence while many series don't.

Comment: @reuns: I've never seen this notion applied to a general series. Can you provide a reference where this notion is used for a general series?

Comment: @levap It is applied here. You may call it "disk of convergence" if you really want to make it clear it is not a power series. Abscissa of convergence (which is a radius of convergence up to a change of variable) and strip of convergence is applied to Fourier series, Laplace transforms, Dirichlet series.

Comment: I also realized that for $|z|=1$ I can just take $z=1$ which shows no convergence on the boundary.

Comment: @reuns I'm with levap on radius of convergence; it's for power series.

Comment: I think the comment suffices to prove the question in the post, but I just want to point out that you can directly use $|\sin(z^{n})|\leq C|z^{n}|$ for all $|z|<1$ (if $z\in\mathbb{D}$, then $z^{n}\in\mathbb{D}$ for sure, so your inequality applies) to conclude the series converges absolutely. As long as it converges absolutely (in the case of complex analysis), then it follows immediately it defines a holomorphic function in the corresponding domain. You can for sure do the M-test, but you will find that it is basically a repetition.