# The boundary behavior of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(z^{n})$ on $|z|=1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

A similar question was asked here: [Analytic function in the open unit disc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389073/analytic-function-in-the-open-unit-disc). It was actually partially solved.

The problem is as follows:

> Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(z^{n})$ defines an analytic function in $|z|<1$. What happens on the boundary?

The first part can be easily proved if one knows that $|\sin(z)|\leq C|z|$ for all $|z|\leq 1$. This can be proved if one considers the power series of $\sin(z)/z$, and the module of the power series is always bounded by the power series of $\sin(z)/z$ at $z=i$, so $\sin(i)/i$ is the maximum, which is $C$.

Okay, now, if $z\in\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, then clearly $z^{n}\in\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Hence, the inequality can be applied to $z^{n}$ so that $$|\sin(z^{n})|\leq C|z^{n}|\ \ \text{for all}\ \ |z|\leq 1.$$

In particular, on $|z|<1$, we have $$\Bigg|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(z^{n})\Bigg|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\sin(z^{n})|\leq C\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|z|^{n}=C\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{n}<\infty,$$ since $r<1$. Thus, the series converges absolutely on $|z|<1$ and thus defines an analytic function on $|z|<1$.

---

Now, I am having trouble analyzing the boundary behavior. Indeed, the series clearly diverges when $z=1$, since then you have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(1)=\sin(1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1=\infty.$$ But can we say something more? Like, perhaps $1$ is the only point that this series diverges?

I tried to use the common trick that $z=e^{2\pi \frac{p}{q}i}$ to show the divergence and use the density, but it seems useless..

Any idea? Thanks for any help!

Comment: use that $|\sin(x+iy)|^2=\sin^2x+\sinh^2y$ to show that $|\sin(x+iy)| \ge c>0, x^2+y^2=1$ hence $|\sin (z^n)| \ge c, |z|=1$ so the series cannot converge (eg if $1 \ge|x| \ge 1/2$ we have $|\sin x| \ge c_1$, otherwise $|y| \ge \sqrt 3/2, so |\sinh y| \ge c_2$)

Comment: @Conrad nice, will update the post in 2-3 hours after a late dinner :) Thank you!

Comment: $\sin(s)$ has no zero on $|s|=1$ so $\inf_{|s|=1} |\sin(s)|=C>0$ and $\sum_n \sin(z^n)$ diverges for $|z|=1$. That said proving that $f(z)=\sum_n \sin(z^n)$ has a natural boundary on $|z|=1$ isn't obvious. Note that $f(z)=\sum_k \frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\frac{z^{2k+1}}{1-z^{2k+1}}$ which is analytic both for $|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$. @Conrad

Comment: @Conrad I have a dumb question. I have proved everything we need: $|\sin(z^{n})|\geq C>0$ for $|z|=1$. But then how could I show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(z^{n})$ diverges? I can only show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\sin(z^{n})|$ diverges, but it does not necessarily imply what we want, right?

Comment: a convergent series has the general term converging to zero, so if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(z^{n})$ would converge, we would need $\sin (z^n) \to 0$

Comment: @Conrad oh oh right. Thanks! That was indeed a dumb question... :)

Comment: happens to miss something obvious if you have something different in mind, no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Conrad's inspiring comment, I derived the following proof:

We firstly consider $|\sin(z)|$. Note that $$\sin(z)=\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cos(iy)+\cos(x)\sin(iy),$$ and $$e^{iy}=\cos(y)+i\sin(y)\implies e^{-y}=e^{i(iy)}=\cos(iy)+i\sin(iy)$$ $$e^{-iy}=\cos(y)-i\sin(y)\implies e^{y}=e^{-i(iy)}=\cos(iy)-i\sin(iy).$$ From these two, one could derive the formula of $\cos(iy)$ and $\sin(iy)$. (I always do this since I can never remember the formula of $\sinh(\cdot)$ and $\cosh(\cdot)$.

After rearranging the real part and imaginary part and taking $\sin(z)\overline{\sin(z)}$, and using $\cos^{2}(x)=1-\sin^{2}(x)$, one could get $$|\sin(z)|^{2}=\dfrac{e^{2y}-2+e^{-2y}}{4}+\sin^{2}(x)\geq \dfrac{e^{2y}-2+e^{-2y}}{4}+0.$$

Now, for $|z|=1$, we have $x,y\in [-1,1]$. Take $f(y):=\frac{e^{2y}-2+e^{-2y}}{4},$ and compute the critical point of it which is $z_{0}=0$, and one could compare as $$f(0)=\dfrac{1}{4}\ \ \text{but}\ \ f(1)=f(-1)=\dfrac{1}{4}\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{e^{2}}+e^{2}\Bigg)>\dfrac{1}{4}\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{9}+4\Bigg)=\dfrac{37}{36}>\dfrac{1}{4},$$ so the absolute minimum of $f(y)$ in $[-1,1]$ is $\dfrac{1}{4}$.

This implies that for $|z|=1$, $$|sin(z)|^{2}\geq \dfrac{1}{4}\implies |\sin(z)|\geq \dfrac{1}{2}.$$

Note that $|z^{n}|=1\iff |z|=1$, so this inequality can be applied to $z^{n}$ so that $$|\sin(z^{n})|\geq C>0\ \text{on}\ |z|=1.$$

This implies that on $|z|=1$, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|\sin(z^{n})|\neq 0\iff\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(z^{n})\neq 0,$$ which means that the original series must diverge on the whole $|z|=1$.

Comment: Here $\dfrac{e^{2y}-2+e^{-2y}}{4}+\sin^{2}(x)$, when $|z|=1$, $x,y$ should satisfy $x^2+y^2=1$, and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: $$\min_{|z|=1}\dfrac{e^{2y}-2+e^{-2y}}{4}+\sin^{2}(x)=\sin^21.$$